# what is seam api?

Tags: java, seam

what is seam api and what are the advantages of using it?

Answer (score 2):

It's referring to [JBoss Seam](http://www.jboss.com/products/seam/), which is an application development framework.

The advantages (or otherwise) would have to be compared with another, comparable, framework, but the above link lists the main features.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest advantages is that Seam functions as a glue between JSF and JPA (front-end and back-end) solidifying and streamlining business logic between the two ends. Of course, similarly to Spring, there are many other valuable features Seam has to offer.